# airbnb/react-dates Display Week Number on DayPickerRangeController

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar, react-dates

Using `DayPickerRangeController` from airbnb/react-dates (12.7.1), I would like to display the week number on the left of the day picker for each weeks.

Here is what I currently have

[image: My Day Picker]

Here is what I would like to see on my calendar

[image: Calendar with weeks number displayed]

Is there any prop that can help or is there an already existing solution?

Answer (score 1):

`airbnb/react-dates` does not support any props to display the week no.
You can have a look at [rc-calender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-calendar) as other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @ShridharBavannawa, there's currently no support for displaying week number. However, there's a related [issue](http://@https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/889) open on github where [Jussi Niinikoski](https://github.com/jussiniinikoski) suggests a hack that help; Instead of displaying week number on the side of each week, one can display them in every date cell with the `renderDayContents` property as follow:

```
renderDayContents={(day) => (
  <>
    <p>{day.format('W')}</p>
    <p>{day.format('D')}</p>
  </>
)
```

Where day would be a [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) object. You can then style the cell to your taste.